# DNS address on a roaming laptop

Tags: domain-name-system

I have a local DNS server that we use for our intranet. Its IP address is 192.168.0.25.

In order to see pages on our intranet, our employees have to use 192.168.0.25 for their DNS server. If they provide two DNS server IP addresses - one local and one remote - it seems to cause problems.

The problem with having just the local domain, though, is that when the employees take their laptops home, they have to remove that local IP address in order for the internet to work.

Is there a way to make it so the employees don't have to change their DNS servers every time they leave the office?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set up a DHCP server and scope on your network for the clients, assign your DNS server in your DHCP scope\server options, set the clients to get their ip address and DNS servers from DHCP, done.

Comment: Agreed.  DHCP configuration should be able to solve this fairly easily.

Comment: +1 Always avoid hardcoding a DNS server address on a non-server machine.